# $\omega$- and $\alpha$-limit sets

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to identify the $\omega$-limit sets and $\alpha$-limit sets of $r' = r-r^2$, and $\theta' = 1$.

I note that the $\omega$-limit sets are essentially sinks and sources are $\alpha$-limit sets, but am confused on the procedure of such.

Also, how can we use this concept to tackle: $r' = r^3 - 3r^2 + 2r$, and $\theta' = 1$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider the system:

$$r' = r(1-r), ~~\text{and}~~ \theta' = 1,$$

where $r \ge 0$.

The radial and angular dynamics are uncoupled and so can be analyzed separately.

Treating $r' = r(1-r)$ as a vector field on the line (plot of $r' vs. r$), we see that $r^*=0$ is an unstable fixed point and $r^*=1$ is stable (plot these).

If we now look at the phase plane, all trajectories (except $r^*=0$) approach the unit circle $r^* = 1$ monotonically.

Since the motion in the $\theta$-direction is simply a rotation at constant angular velocity, we see that all trajectories spiral asymptotically toward a limit cycle at $r=1$.

Note, you can also plot solutions as a function of time, for example, you know, from polar coordinates, what $x(t)$ is. Start a trajectory outside the limit cycle and see if it settles down to the limit cycle.

You can now use this as a model to do the next one.

For the second one, you can write:

$$r' = r^3 - 3r^2 +2r = r(r^2-3r+2) = r(r-1)(r-2), ~~\theta' = 1.$$

Using the previous example, you should be able to analyze.

Comment: could you add in the plots for the detail? I also dont see the info on alpha-limit sets.

Comment: @RichardWang: This was intended to kick start you and help move you forward. Unfortunately, I don't have an automated tool to plot this. Regards

Comment: I was just confused with the explanation. I dont see the stable sources and sinks

Comment: In which directions do the flows go from a source? Is that stable or unstable? In which direction do the flows go for a sink? Is that stable or unstable? Is that clear? Regards

Comment: Nice work, Amzoti! +1

Comment: I know...the close/open thing is really playing out... to the detriment of the site, I suspect.